# How do I fix my code to update the second fragment after clicking on items in a listview of the first fragment in Android Studio using Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm learning to make an app which shows a brief city guide based of a few cities I have added in the listview of the first fragment. However, whenever I select a city, the second fragment doesn't updates and shows the correct results.
Following is the Main activity code:

```
package com.example.CG;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements fragment_A.OnFragmentInteractionListener, fragment_B.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int position) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Activity log--> Item " + position + " selected!");
        FragmentManager FragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager() ;
        fragment_B fragB = (fragment_B) FragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.fragB);
        fragB.update_text(position) ;
    }
}
```

Fragment A code:

```
package com.example.CG;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link fragment_A#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class fragment_A extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public fragment_A() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment fragment_A.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static fragment_A newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        fragment_A fragment = new fragment_A();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__a, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListView listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        String[] cities = resources.getStringArray(R.array.citiesNames);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, cities);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Fragment log--> Item " + position + " selected!");
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onFragmentInteraction(position);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(int position);
    }
}
```

Fragment B code:

```
package com.example.CG;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link fragment_B#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class fragment_B extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private TextView frag2_text;
    public fragment_B() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment fragment_B.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static fragment_B newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        fragment_B fragment = new fragment_B();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__b, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        frag2_text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    }

    public void update_text(int position){
        frag2_text.setText("Item " + position + " clicked.");
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(int position);
    }
}
```

Strings.XML:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">CG</string>
    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
    <string name="textView">Hello there</string>

    <string-array name="citiesNames">
        <item>New York</item>
        <item>LA</item>
        <item>Seattle</item>
        <item>Boston</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Logcat:

```
5:03:59.979  9022-9047  EGL_emulation           com.example.lab03                    D  app_time_stats: avg=525.21ms min=2.28ms max=1544.37ms count=3
2023-06-03 15:04:00.014  9022-9022  TAG                     com.example.lab03                    D  Fragment log--> Item 3 selected!
2023-06-03 15:04:00.689  9022-9022  TAG                     com.example.lab03                    D  Fragment log--> Item 2 selected!
2023-06-03 15:04:00.985  9022-9047  EGL_emulation           com.example.lab03                    D  app_time_stats: avg=19.33ms min=0.79ms max=226.90ms count=48
2023-06-03 15:04:01.398  9022-9022  TAG                     com.example.lab03                    D  Fragment log--> Item 1 selected!
2023-06-03 15:04:02.002  9022-9047  EGL_emulation           com.example.lab03                    D  app_time_stats: avg=16.94ms min=13.61ms max=31.34ms count=60
2023-06-03 15:04:02.348  9022-9022  TAG                     com.example.lab03                    D  Fragment log--> Item 0 selected!
2023-06-03 15:04:03.018  9022-9047  EGL_emulation           com.example.lab03                    D  app_time_stats: avg=17.82ms min=14.39ms max=84.72ms count=57
2023-06-03 15:04:03.206  9022-9022  TAG                     com.example.lab03                    D  Fragment log--> Item 1 selected!
2023-06-03 15:04:04.775  9022-9047  EGL_emulation           com.example.lab03                    D  app_time_stats: avg=28.80ms min=14.03ms max=759.77ms count=61
```

So in the logcat, it should also output the results for  `Log.d("TAG", "Activity log--> Item " + position + " selected!");` that I am missing. Its neither updating the activity nor the second fragment.